# How to deal with many subpages in an Android app?

Tags: android, design, app, page-layout

I'm currently developing an Android app which has already plenty of pages in its navigation, so I don't want to add much more to it.

Now I have a page, let's call it **marketplace**. The **marketplace** had many different market stands with different activities, on some you can buy stuff, on others take part in a lottery, etc. I need to display these activities (about 15) in the **marketplace** page.

I didn't want to just put them all on the market page directly because it would end up in a lot of scrolling (which is bad).

My second idea was to put a list on the market page with buttons with the name of the market stand (herbs, lottery, etc.) on the market page and create subpages for each market stand.
This doesn't require much scrolling, but still doesn't look good or feels really intentional.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: visual examples would be nice

Comment: @downrep_nation http://puu.sh/q2wUJ/83fcbfc15e.png the list with the market stands and http://puu.sh/q2xvu/66731da55d.png one of the market stands. Both in German, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be some kind of fantasy environment, why not take it literally and display market stands as market stands on a map of a village's market. Your users will get accustomed to the visual representation of your market stands really quickly.

Comment: I ended up using tabs, but that would also be an interesting idea... But I don't have the fitting images for something like that and they would need to be unique and recognizable, because there are 15 of them (on one page)

Comment: A slippy-map type view would be perfect for the task and make your game visually appealing!

Comment: In general, yes. In this case, no because it is a text-only game (very rare images for spells and items) ;)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, at least a single scroll in necessary in any case. as 15 entries cannot be shown properly on a single screen with keeping screen tidy. So the only option you have is to make your UI attractive. Instead of adding buttons you can use card layout. (see the image below). [image]

You can add a small animation where the card clicked will open up and display some more information. This will make the ui interactive and would not bore the user.For animation example, see the image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like some Information Architecture could help, group the categories themselves and display those higher-level groupings so as to allow the User to drill-down. "Herbs" does not seem to be well categories alongside "lottery".